# "letztes Hochschulzeugnis"

Tags: meaning

Ich bin im dritten Semester meines Masterstudium und möchte mich als ein Werkstudent bewerben. Eine der geforderten Bewerbungsunterlagen ist "letztes Hochschulzeugnis". Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich dafür mein Bachelorabschlusszeugnis oder die Noten von den letzten Semestern abgeben muss.

Comment: Es schadet sicher nicht, beides einzureichen oder nachzufragen. Rein sprachlich und rechtlich sind die Noten der letzten Semester kein Zeugnis, aber es zählt ja, was der Arbeitgeber meint.

Comment: Zu einer Bewerbung gehören idR Abschlussschul-, Hochschul- und Arbeitszeugnisse, also auch das des Bachelorabschlusses. Da mit "letztes Hochschulzeugnis" höchstwahrscheinlich der aktuelle Notenspiegel gemeint ist, wird man eh beides einreichen.

Comment: einfach mal dort anrufen!

Answer (score 5):

Studiendokumentation, Scheine -- oder wie man Nachweise für Modulnoten sonst noch nennt -- werden üblicher Weise nicht in den Bewerbungsunterlagen erwartet. Von Zeugnis ist dabei in der Regel nicht mehr die Rede.

Denkbar wäre, "letztes Hochschulzeugnis" beziehe sich auf Bachelor *oder* Master-Zeugnis. Alles andere wäre sprachlich unsauber.

Comment: Mag ja sprachlich unsauber sein, aber wenn ich Bewerbungen vor mir liegen habe, interessieren mich die Noten natürlich viel mehr als das reine Abschlusszeugnis (oder noch weniger Informationsgehalt: Die Urkunde, die nicht mal die Abschlussnote enthält).

Answer (score 4):

Im Zusammenhang mit einer Bewerbung ist davon auszugehen, dass mit „letztes Hochschulzeugnis“ die offizielle Urkunde gemeint ist, die den höchsten akademischen Grad be*zeugt*, den der Bewerber bis dato erworben hat. Hier konkret also das Bachelorzeugnis.

Der [Hochschulabschluss](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hochschulabschluss) ist laut Duden ein „an einer Hochschule erworbenes [Abschlusszeugnis](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abschlusszeugnis)“, bezieht sich also auf die Erlangung eines akademischen Grades. Hat die Bewerberin davon mehrere, zum Beispiel Bachelor, Master und Doktor, dann ist nur der zu*letzt* erworbene – und mithin höchste – Grad relevant, da dieser die anderen Abschlüsse bedingt.

Answer (score 3):

Der Begriff *»Zeugnis«* ist nicht klar definiert.

Im Fall der Schulzeugnisse ist das noch einigermaßen klar, dann ist ein Zeugnis die Zusammenfassung aller Leistungsbeurteilungen des zu Ende gegangenen Schuljahres, die man von der Schule bekommt. Es ist eine öffentliche Urkunde. Zusätzlich bekommen Schüler am Ende des ersten Halbjahres auch noch eine Schulnachricht. Zumindest war das bei mir so, ich habe zwischen 1970 und 1983 in Graz die Schulbank gedrückt. Diese Schulnachricht ist aber kein Zeugnis.

Im Bereich der Hochschulen kann es sein, dass man für jedes Fach ein einzelnes Zeugnis bekommt. Wenn das der Fall ist, sammelt man während eines Studienjahres ein rundes Dutzend Zeugnisse an, darauf steht jeweils eine einzelne Note. So war das jedenfalls bei mir, als ich vor rund 30 Jahren Physik und Chemie studiert habe (ebenfalls in Graz).

Später habe ich an Fachhochschulen studiert (in Wien und jetzt gerade in St. Pölten), da gibt es am Ende jedes Semesters ein Zeugnis mit den Noten aller Fächer, also genau zwei Zeugnisse pro Studienjahr.

Was bei Hochschulen und Fachhochschulen aber gleich ist, ist das Abschlusszeugnis, das man bekommt, wenn man die Abschlussprüfung bestanden hat. In diesem Dokument steht aber nur das Ergebnis der Abschlussprüfung, also genau eine Beurteilung, aus der sich aber nicht darauf schließen lässt, mit welchen Noten man die Studienfächer abgeschlossen hat.

Wenn dein potentieller zukünftiger Arbeitgeber also dein letztes Hochschulzeugnis verlangt, dann würde ich ihm das Abschlusszeugnis geben, falls du dein Studium schon abgeschlossen hast. Um ganz sicher zu gehen, empfehle ich aber nachzufragen, was genau gemeint ist.

Answer (score 2):

Nach dem Lesen von Huberts Antwort bin ich geneigt zu sagen, dass es da wohl sehr große regionale Unterschiede gibt. Daher solltest Du am besten hinzufügen, wo Du studierst und wo das Unternehmen, bei dem Du Dich bewerben willst, seinen Sitz hat.

Zur allgemeinen Bedeutung des Wortes "Zeugnis":
Ich bin in Berlin (West) zur Schule gegangen (1974 bis 87), und im Gegensatz zu Huberts Antwort hießen bei uns auch die Dokumente nach dem ersten Halbjahr **Zeugnis** - Halbjahreszeugnis, um genau zu sein, aber eben offiziell *Zeugnis*, und sie unterschieden sich auch optisch nicht von den Jahreszeugnissen. Für die Versetzung in die nächste Klasse war das Jahreszeugnis ausschlaggebend, während das Halbjahreszeugnis nur einmal wirkliche Relevanz besaß, nämlich in der 7ten Klasse (Berlin hat eine 6jährige Grundschule), denn da gab es auf dem Gymnasium bzw. der Realschule das Probehalbjahr - wer da zu schlechte Noten hatte, wurde auf die nächst niedrigere Schulstufe "heruntergereicht" (Gymnasium --> Realschule oder Realschule --> Hauptschule).

Im Studium hingegen (Technische Universität Berlin) gab es überhaupt keine regelmäßigen Zwischenzeugnisse. Für die einzelnen belegten Fächer gab es sogenannte *Scheine*, die vor allem *Teilnahmebescheinigungen* darstellten - ob zum Erhalt auch ein Leistungsnachweis (Klausur oder mündliche Rücksprache) oder nur regelmäßige Anwesenheit nötig war, hing vom jeweiligen Fach ab. Nach Absolvierens aller Veranstaltungen des Grundstudiums, wenn man alle erforderlichen Scheine vorgelegt und die (mündlichen) Prüfungen zur Diplomvorprüfung bestanden hatte, gab es das Vordiplomszeugnis (ähnlich, aber nicht identisch mit dem Bachelor).
Nachdem man in ähnlicher Weise alle Pflichtveranstaltungen des Hauptstudiums absolviert, erneut (mündliche) Prüfungen abgelegt sowie eine Diplomarbeit eingereicht hatte, bekam man bei Erfolg zwei Unterlagen: Ein Diplom*zeugnis* mit Auflistung der einzelnen Noten (Diplomarbeit und die 4 Prüfungen) und der errechneten Gesamtnote, sowie eine Diplom*urkunde* ohne jegliche Note.

In dem von Dir konkret geschilderten Fall schließe ich mich daher Huberts Empfehlung an, nachzufragen - oder, falls die Zeit drängt, wie Roland in seinem Kommentar vorgeschlagen hat, *sowohl* das Bachelorabschlusszeugnis *als auch* das aktuellste Semesterzeugnis einzureichen.

P.S.
Studium der Physik - in anderen Fächern mögen die Art (mündlich/schriftlich) und die Anzahl der abzulegenden Prüfungen anders sein.